# @ annotations not working anymore

Tags: android, android-studio

I have defined this @IntDef

```
public static final int LINE = 0;
public static final int CORNER = 1;

@IntDef({LINE, CORNER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface ShapeTypes {}
```

and assigned it to one of my class members like this

```
public @ShapeTypes int shapeType;
```

and if I remember correctly, it used to work, but now, in **Android Studio 3.1.2** I'm able to do something like this

```
myClassObj.shapeType = 99;
```

Shouldn't it cause compilation and/or runtime errors? Is there a way I can define range of allowed values for the variables now?

**Update**
It seems, that all annotations are not working anymore.

```
@IntRange(from = 4, to = 18)
public int size;
```

does not affect the statement `size = 20;`

Am I missing something? Some setting to turn on the annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having same problem in Android Studio 3.1.2. But one of my colleagues tested it in 3.1.0 and it seems it is working in that version.

Comment: So, it's a 3.1.2. bug then? Or are they planning to exclude this feature?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a bug in 3.1.2. Excluding this feature would be meaningless.

Comment: Annotations are working in 3.2 Canary, so I guess it's a bug in 3.1.2.

Answer (score -1):

`IntDef` treat like `enum` so you can't initialize later. You have declare manually.

```
@IntDef({ShapeTypes.SHAPETYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@interface ShapeTypes {
    int SHAPETYPE= 0;
}
```

For more details have look [this](http://blog.shamanland.com/2016/02/int-string-enum.html)

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. I'm trying to allow only values from ShapeTypes interface to shapeType variable. And it seems that link you've provided states this possible: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0Bwh0SNLPmjQBT2hSMlJ6OXZrV3c
But I don't get this error, when I try to assign a value out of range